Package updates often cause build error "Cannot find module 'ajv-formats'"
The error happens when building Angular project with ng serve and ng build after updating packages.
It's been reported multiple times in Angular CLI repo (#22780, #24291, #27724) and on StackOverflow (#73816689) but that didn't help to solve it once and for all.
Backstory. We use Dependabot and in our setup it creates minor version upgrade pull requests throughout the week and merges all of them every Monday morning, which triggers update of the server.
Often times it results in the build error An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'ajv-formats'.
The "fix" it is to delete yarn.lock locally, reinstall node_modules and push the fresh yarn.lock file.
After doing so, with the help of version control system, you can see the "healing" changes in yarn.lock. Kind of annoying to do this few times a month.
Main question: how to fix it once and for all?
Also where exactly is the culprit? Why are there issues in minor version updates?
Angular CLI contributor suggests that:

This issue is likely caused by an older version of schema-utils, a transitive dependency in your node_modules directory. Versions prior to 4.0.0 did not correctly list ajv-formats as a dependency, which can lead to incorrect module hoisting.

I checked and found that 7 dependencies use the older than 4.0.0 versions of schema-utils.
Here's my setup:
Angular CLI: 17.3.8
Node: 20.10.0
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.19
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.3.10
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, material-moment-adapter
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router, service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.8
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.8
@angular/cli                    17.3.8
@angular/fire                   17.0.1
@schematics/angular             17.3.8
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.4.5
webpack                         5.91.0
zone.js                         0.14.6

